# How did the early Macintosh computers update the display?

Tags: graphics, apple-macintosh

This question is about the Macintosh 128k, but if you can give an answer which describes one of the other very similar machines, that's good too.

The bitmap was 512 by 384 pixels. Assuming that one byte stores eight pixels, so that the CPU can read or update 16 bits in a single bus cycle, that means it would take 10 944 bus cycles to re-write the entire display. Assuming it used something like a `move.w a0+, a1+` which is 12 cycles, I calculate that to take around 0.3 seconds to copy a bitmap onto the screen, at 8 MHz. Add to that a variable number of `roxl` or `roxr` instructions (in case you want to scroll or move something some pixels to the left or right), and overhead for even a generously unrolled loop, you've got a dog slow GUI.

Another problem is that we have a mouse, but apparently no sprite hardware. So now we need to copy around a (partial) shadow of the bitmap, overlaying the cursor with `and` and `or`, whenever the user moves the mouse.

[This link](https://web.archive.org/web/20080514165755/http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=112162) does not list any hardware which was obviously intended to alleviate these problems.

So how did this line of "classic macs" address the problem of scrolling and moving large areas, or rendering a mouse cursor?

Comment: Even 8-bit systems with no sprite hardware at all could comfortably handle a mouse cursor and a graphical environment  (See WIMP systems for example, for the Amstrad machines or the ZX Spectrum) Shouldn't be a problem for a fast 68k CPU.

Comment: I can't replicate you maths. 512 x 384 = 196,608 bits = 12,288 words x 12 clock cycles for `move.w a0+, a1+` = 147,456 cycles at 8MHz = 0.018 seconds or just over 50Hz,

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't have to rewrite every pixel on the screen during every vertical blank - and indeed, very few machines did that back then. The Windows UI model still works this way (though only for the "software" rendering part), though many applications stopped doing that for simplicity. The pixels you wrote 10 seconds ago are still in the video buffer, unless you explicitly overwrote them - you don't start with an empty buffer on each "frame".

Comment: FYI, “Macintosh” was never plural in Apple-speak. So, “Macintosh computers”, not “Macintoshes”.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Formally, trademarks are supposed to be adjectives rather than nouns.  Thus, one would build things with Lego® brand blocks, or play the SCRABBLE® brand crossword game, or--of course--use the Macintosh® brand computer.  The owners of trademarks cannot be expected to sue everyone who uses their marks as nouns, but in theory are supposed to avoid such usage themselves.

Comment: One import detail is that "scrolling and moving large areas" wasn't something that happened very much on the original Mac UI.  For example, window drags didn't drag the whole opaque window in classic MacOS.  You dragged the title bar of a window, and it just showed a frame of the outline of where the window would go.  Drawing four stippled lines every frame as you drag the window is easy even with a terrible CPU and RAM as slow as molasses.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There were three important design aspects of the original Macintosh that allowed the relatively limited video display hardware to provide a pleasing user experience in terms of the performance of its GUI.

1. Vertical blanking hardware interrupt - this provided the necessary    timing for software to synchronize display updates to the CRT    refresh cycle. Thus, smooth animation could be achieved, especially    when combined with #2.
2. Double-buffered display support - the hardware supported two independent display buffers that could be rapidly toggled. This allowed redraws that took longer than the blanking interval to appear synchronous with the CRT refresh cycle.
3. Highly-optimized QuickDraw - about 1/3 of the Macintosh ROM firmware was used to give programmers reusable, highly-optimized, assembly language drawing routines for primitives like lines, ovals, rectangles, and fonts. These drawing routines were in turn used by the ROM GUI routines, which were used by virtually all applications programmers.

In summary, QuickDraw was a rather brilliant inclusion that made it easy for applications to **quickly** **redraw** only those **regions** of the display that they modified. When this optimization was not enough for performance, synchronization with the video display allowed the lag in re-drawing the display to still appear sufficiently smooth and "unbroken" so that a responsive user feel was evoked.

**NOTE** 1: The visible display was actually 342 lines, not 384.

**NOTE** 2: Since the display hardware shares access to DRAM with the CPU during each horizontal drawing cycle, the CPU effectively runs at ~6 MHz, not ~8 MHz.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the standard GUI wasn't doubled buffered.That would require a fair chunk of the 128K memory for the second buffer, and would make updating only the part of the screen that needed updating much more complicated. It also would mean that you wouldn't need to do anything to avoid flicker like described here: http://www.computerhistory.org/atchm/macpaint-and-quickdraw-source-code/ "Bill eliminated the flicker by composing everything in a hidden memory buffer, which was then transferred to the screen quickly when it was completely ready."

Comment: As an aside, the sound generator was tied directly to the screen refresh, basically the screen logic (I forget the details) was the clock that drove the Sound hardware.

Comment: @RossRidge All early Macs supported an *alternate screen buffer* that started at $12700 ($72700 on the Fat Mac) and was activated by setting a specific bit in the VIA data register.

Comment: @tofro I'm not disputing whether the hardware support existed, but whether it was used during the display of the standard GUI.

Comment: @RossRidge I don't know whether the standard GUI used page flipping (I guess like you that it didn't), but GameSprocket much later supported it.

Comment: Note also that e.g. dragging a window was done by dragging only the outline, and the window was only redrawn in the new location when you let go of it.

Comment: Of note, classic MS Windows also works on the principle of making it an application's responsibility to restore window content that was damaged by something obscuring it....

Answer (score 47):

**TL;DR:** Exactly as you assume. The CPU shovelled the data around, even way slower than your calculation suggests, and everyone was happy about the high speed with which it happened :)

---

To be honest, I'm not complete sure what your question is. It was a plain bitmap display (like you assumed) and quite sufficient to be handled by the CPU. After all, no-one was thinking of real time video back then. Just a UI and whatever the running application wants to display. And for this a CPU is quite sufficient.

Moving a mouse cursor needs at maximum the manipulation of twice 16 bytes (in case of an 8x8). One for undrawing the existing one, one for drawing it at a new position. That's few enough when done every frame for a fast moving one. In reality the mouse doesn't move at all most of the time, so no redraw is needed.

Similar, the display doesn't get changed a lot. Sure, every time a key gets pressed a character is to be drawn. Not a big deal. Several can be done between frames.

Worst case here would be scrolling up at the end of a line, or inserting a character in the topmost line of a window. This may take time to (re)draw the entire window, but then again, it's a rare case and even if it lags by like .2 seconds, it's way acceptable.

Yes, the Mac **was** slow in drawing a whole screen, but it wasn't exceptionally slow, or slower than other machines of that time. Especially not considering the nice look it had :))

Just compare it to similar machines of about the same time frame. Inserting a character at a top line and wrapping the rest down equals a redraw of the whole text screen. On a 9,600 bps terminal that equals to more than **two whole seconds**. An Apple II with its built-in 40x24 screen needed about 0.04 seconds (already more than 2 frames) to do the same (*1) and with an 80 column card it may have taken as much as .1 seconds. So while one could notice a little lag when scrolling on a Mac, it was way within its competition.

Today we are used to instantly updated of humungous high resolution screens, no matter what happens. Back then no-one watched videos on a PC. Heck, simple animations of a few pixels were already considered awesome.

**Bottom line, there was no such problem.**

---

*1 - That's hand written assembly optimized for that case.

Comment: +1. It’s easy to forget how few screen updates there were in old GUIs; scrolling didn’t update contents in real time, nor did moving windows etc.

Comment: Did the CPU have `BITBLT`? That can be useful for scrolling.

Comment: This answer misses the key thing that made it appear fast: an incredible amount of coding effort went into only updating those portions of the screen that actually needed updating.  I recently re-wrote some drawing code originally written in the early-Macintosh era: the new code has about a third as many lines, is much less complex, and takes five times longer to draw.

Comment: @Barmar Huh? BitBlt is a Windows API, not a CPU instruction.

Comment: @duskwuff: [BitBLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit) had been a thing long before there was a Windows API function of the same name.

Comment: Systems with a `BITBLT` instruction typically had microcoded CPUs, e.g. Alto, Star, Lisp Machines, and so on. Most commercial microprocessors like the 68000 did not have one.

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind is that *scan-out* of the display is not *update* of the display. Most things on the screen don’t need to change during display update in a typical GUI, while scan-out from display memory to video is done by special hardwrae rather than by the CPU on virtually all systems (including Apple II, Lisa, and Macintosh, as well as most of their contemporaries).

Comment: Ha ha, they also crashed A LOT.  And still we didn't mind.  That's just how it was!

Comment: Programs running on terminals didn't/don't re-send the entire textual contents over the line on scrolling. They set a scrolling region and insert/delete lines or just let it naturally scroll on linefeed at the end of the region.

Comment: @R.. Sure - if that terminal did support such high level functions. Many did not. Similar, LF scrolling on a glass TTY will destroy any non scrolling region above the text area and is impossible when there is a non scrolling text below the scrolling region - like one may have with a text editor or similar. Grab an ADM3A manual for a reality check - or something luxurious as a Hazeltine 1500 :)) **Equaly important: You might want to reread what has been writen before posting - the terminal remark was about one character being inserted in the top most line. Imagine word processing.**

Answer (score 21):

As others have said, refreshing the whole screen in a fraction of a second was considered *blindingly fast* at that time.

The Mac's biggest early advantage, though, was the [QuickDraw framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickDraw). This was leaps and bounds ahead of other graphics packages of the day, both in functionality and efficiency. With QuickDraw, you rarely *had* to rewrite the whole display -- instead, you'd work within a GrafPort representing a window's content pane, and manipulate Regions that touched only affected pixels, not an entire rectangular bounding box.

At the time the Mac was introduced, a 16-bit 8-MHz 68000 was actually respectably fast in comparison to its competition. But it *felt* AMAZINGLY fast.

Comment: I had an 8086 PC in the 80s, with the GEM desktop. Screen scrolling took about 2 seconds. The Mac was relatively quick for the time.

Comment: Also QuickDraw had an extremely well optimized bitblt which (in addition to the high level features like only moving content within a window - which was a subset of the entire screen) made moving pixels as fast as possible.  Windows 2 and 3, a few years later, had a bitblt which would _generate code on the fly and then execute it_ to achieve blindingly fast pixel updates.  I feel sure (though don't actually know for a fact) that QuickDraw did that too, because similar things were being done in games and such at the time.

Comment: The Atari ST's VDI and Line-A graphics wasn't much worse.

Comment: While Quickdraw was originally written in C, there were 6 (or 8?) "bottleneck" functions through which all of QD did its stuff.  This allowed acceleration and other customization without having to change QD at all.

e.g., while not a direct example, two of the bottleneck functions were for drawing text and measuring text.  Later when Apple switched to the PowerPC processor, Apple optimized those bottleneck functions for PowerPC. So Excel, spending 70% of its time, typically, in the toolbox call DrawString(), was 70% native code just by Apple rewriting those 2 bottleneck funcs.

Comment: And Bill Atkinson had actually a patent for rounded corners :-) (Effiicent graphic operations restricted to an arbitrary area, for example a rectangle with rounded corners).

Answer (score 10):

Basically all early 68k Home Computers (Classic Mac, early Atari ST, Sinclair QL) would update the display using the CPU only. The Amiga with its Blitter Chip was an exception (somewhat copied by the Atari ST when that one later on got a - simpler - Blitter).

Without support from specific graphics or DMA chips, there were still some ways to speed up graphics operations:

- Double(/multiple) buffering - This didn't really make the shoving around of pixels faster, but made it *look fast* (because updates were basically instant). The CPU could write in one memory bank while the video circuitry displayed the other. Mac, Atari ST and Sinclair QL used / could use this technique.
- Make use of vast amounts of memory - Some Atari ST games used up to 8 pre-shifted screens and switched between them with the above method to implement fast pixel-wise horizontal scrolling (not an option for the early Mac because of its memory limits).
- Vertical scolling by changing the start address of the displayed video buffer - This technique was often used by the Atari ST that was able to modify the address of the first line displayed from video memory in scanline granularity (I do think, however, that the Mac screen banks were fixed)
- Highly optimized machine code screen drivers - The fastest way to shove video memory around using a 68000 CPU is actually the `MOVEM` instruction - Free up as much registers as you can, then move memory around with some code like the following:

  ```
       lea.l sourceAddr,a6
       lea.l destAddr,a5
       move.w #count-1,d0
   lp: movem.l (a6)+,d1-d7/a0-a4
       movem.l d0-d7/a0-a4,(a5)+
       dbra d0,lp
  ```

So, you can actually do faster than your code examples imply.

Seen from today's viewpoint, Mac or Atari ST screen handling isn't really fast. Back in the days, however, it was - It was way faster than most of what people were used from 8-bit CPUs.

Comment: And back then, many people were still used to teleterminals, both CRT and actual printers. Even with the complexity of the UI, the Mac was blazingly fast - back then. To modern eyes, it's unbearably slow - everything except for moving the mouse had significant very visible delays, especially when you needed to redraw the whole screen (which meant the redraw optimizations didn't apply).

Answer (score 4):

In those old macs, the CPU was basically it.  There was no screen controller, no floppy controller, nothing.  Drawing the screen was job 1.  Handling the floppy and watching for mouse/keyboard interrupts was job 2, and running your program was job 3. Mostly you got time when the electron gun was pulling back from the bottom of the screen to the top after it drew a page, and when it was pulling back horizontally after it drew a line. It felt responsive, but if you wanted to do something compute intensive you had the wrong machine.

Comment: While you are somewhat right, that creates the wrong impression - The Mac was considered a fast computer when it appeared.

Comment: @tofro A fast *home* computer, yes. And it was "portable", and with a full graphical UI to boot. Game consoles were much faster thanks to their dedicated graphics hardware. The large computers like LISP machines had both the UI and usually were a bit faster, but also much larger and decidedly not home machines; and of course, almost noöne had any experience with those; most people either had experience with computers like Apple II or Amiga, or "IBM mainframes" with teletype or CRT terminals. The Mac was quite a special thing.

Comment: @Luaan Game consoles contemporary to the early Mac were Colocovision or Atari 5200, the Famicom and, a bit later, the NES. None of these were close to a Mac (in performance, display resolution, and, very obviously also, price)

Comment: @tofro That depends on what you count as performance. For a game console, latency was important, while resolution wasn't. For a GUI-based micro-computer, resolution was very important, while latency wasn't. They both had their design goals and achieved tham. The Famicom had pretty much no visible latency while doing animations and full-screen scrolling (in SMB2). The same was true with Atari 2600 (with even lower resolution and graphics quality). Neither could ever work as a home computer with a moused-based GUI, but that wasn't their purpose anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers cover QuickDraw pretty well.  The lack of a hardware mouse cursor was something of a problem from a UI perspective, however, which deserves additional detail.  The cursor drawing could be handled by the vertical-blank interrupt at times when nothing was going on.  The cursor was 16x16, and the CPU could load and store 32-bit registers at any 16-bit boundary, so for 16 lines of the display the CPU would load 32 bits (two 16-bit words), store them to a backup area, mask with the cursor, and write back.  Then the next time it would draw the cursor, it would first restore the part of the screen under the old one.  The cursor and mask could be stored shifted to line up with the current cursor position (so if the cursor moves right three pixels, they'd need to be shifted in the buffer before the next time they're drawn), so that unless the cursor moves by 8 pixels in a single frame it would never be necessary to perform an 8-bit shift (the worst-case value).

The problem arises if the cursor is moved while content is being drawn.  In early versions of the Macintosh firmware, before anything could be drawn on the screen, it was necessary to first hide the cursor (restoring what was behind it), then perform the graphical operation, and then restore the cursor.  The system would do this automatically if the cursor was enabled when drawing was attempted, but doing so imposed a huge speed penalty.  Most programs instead called `HideCursor` before doing a sequence of operations, and then `ShowCursor` afterward.  Calling `HideCursor` would increment a counter and `ShowCursor` would decrement it, so if the cursor was hidden while a function was called that would also hide and restore the cursor, the cursor would still be hidden after the function returned.

A later version of the OS added a major improvement: `ShieldCursor`.  This function took a rectangle, would hide the cursor immediately if it was within that rectangle, and *would also cause the vertical-blank interrupt to show or hide the cursor based upon whether it was within that rectangle*.  This was a major win from both a performance and user-experience standpoint.  If code was going to draw some stuff in a rectangular region of the screen and the cursor wasn't there, there was no need to spend time erasing and redrawing the cursor.  Further, if a program called `ShieldCursor` to guard one area of the screen where the cursor happened to be, and later used it to guard another, there was no need to redraw the cursor immediately.  If the first area needed to be re-shielded and the cursor hadn't been redrawn, there would be no need for an extra redraw/erase cycle.  But if the cursor was moved before that area was re-shielded, the cursor could be made visible.

Early versions of the Macintosh OS and programs for it tended to have the cursor disappear quite a lot, which significantly degraded the user experience.  I don't remember exactly when ShieldCursor was added, but I think it was around the time of the Macintosh II, and it made things much nicer.  I think the mechanisms are simple enough that it probably could have been included within the first Mac OS if anyone had thought of it, but hindsight is of course 20/20.